# How to create a composite video with iOS SDK

Tags: ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, core-video

I realize this is a difficult question without a straightforward answer, but I'm hoping for some suggestions of frameworks or libraries I should start with.

Imagine a view that contains a background image, some smaller images overlaid, and a small video (an MPMoviePlayerController view) overlaid. What I need to do is create a composite video of the entire view. So the final result saved to disk would be all the images and the video combined into one video file.

What AV tools are available that would be most likely to help accomplish this?

Comment: kind of like picplaypost app? You best bet is searching on google or cocoacontrols.com. Its always a challenge to get an answer on these broad questions. If you do end up writing your own code and have a specific problem then quite a few people may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AVAssetWriter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetWriter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) seems to be the best option for doing this.